# How can I pick up the dog in the bar in Cave Story?

Tags: cave-story

So, twice I've played Cave Story as Curly, and both times, when I reach Jenka and go out to collect dogs, I can't pick one of them up. It's the one called Hajime, I think, and he's the one in the backroom of where we first meet Curly (or the real protagonist, depending on the version you're playing). Everytime I try to pick him up, it goes 'Arf!' and then nothing happens. I've never had this problem with any of the other dogs, and I didn't have this issue when I wasn't playing as Curly. What do I do?

EDIT: so, I tried replaying as Quote up to that point, and I can't pick up the dog there either. So I now have three games, with both characters, where I can't do that same thing. am I missing something? does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: If Kotsu's answer helped you, be sure to mark it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark by the number!

Comment: I totally didn't see that. I'm sorry, I'm dreadfully new. Thank you too.

Comment: No worries, sir or madam! I'm just tryin' to help out! Welcome to Gaming!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you speak to the NPC right outside of that room - he says to you that if you're going to visit the old lady that you better take the dog in the other room with you. Once you speak to him and the old lady, you'll be able to pick the dog up.

Answer (score 0):

To get that dog to come with you need to talk to the guy just to the left of the door before going into the bedroom. But, you may run into a situation where he may say to you, "I have nothing to say to you." If you run into this you need to talk to the girl on the right who asks you a "Yes/No" question. Answer, no, to her and this will trigger the man on the left to tell you to take the dog with you. At this point, you can go talk to the dog and he will follow you.